# Subversion: Need to find out what has been ignored in a repository

Tags: svn, mercurial

Bigger picture:

I'm working with an SVN code base, and I'd like to have a local Mercurial repository for my local version control. In creating the Mercurial repository, I want to know what files are set to be ignored by SVN (e.g. temporary files that are created, etc).

What I *really* want is to find the patterns that are used to ignore. So if SVN is told to ignore *.sdf, I don't want to see all the sdf files it is ignoring. I want to see *.sdf so that I can put it in my .hgignore file.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install hgsubversion extension
2. Clone SVN-repo to Mercurial repo
3. Use `hg svn genignore` in order to build .hgignore from `svn:ignore` definitions in tree

Check content of generated file, fix possible errors and don't forget to commit in into you Mercurial

### Sample

If I have repository with such (bad and ugly, but *good for testing*) `svn:ignore` in tree

```
WC>svn pg svn:ignore -v -R
Properties on '.':
  svn:ignore
    *.bak
    *.tmp

Properties on '1':
  svn:ignore
    *.bak
    *.tmp
    *.dbg
    *.raw

Properties on '1\2':
  svn:ignore
    *.bak
    *.tmp
    *.dbg
    *.raw
    *.1bg
```

generated `.hgignore` will be

```
.hgignore
syntax:glob
*.bak
*.tmp
1/*.bak
1/*.tmp
1/*.dbg
1/*.raw
1/2/*.bak
1/2/*.tmp
1/2/*.dbg
1/2/*.raw
1/2/*.1bg
```

which, obviously, can and must be optimized and compacted. N

### Note

In case of using in SVN 1.8+ `svn:global-ignores` (preferred and more readable somehow)

```
WC>svn pg svn:global-ignores -v -R
Properties on '.':
  svn:global-ignores
    *.bak
    *.tmp

Properties on '1':
  svn:global-ignores
    *.dbg
    *.raw

Properties on '1\2':
  svn:global-ignores
    *.1bg
```

current Mercurial|HGSubversion does not use and ignore this property in genignore

### Note 2

At least Mercurial 2.11 can't clone local (`file:///`) Subversion 1.8+ repositories, they must be served by httpd or svnserve

Comment: Haven't tried it, but that definitely looks lazier (and in this case better) :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll can recursively call `svn propget svn:ignore` in your directory structure.

A first pass hacky solution (in bash) is something like:

```
svn list -R | xargs -I{} svn propget svn:ignore {}
```

but this:

1. doesn't show the directory for the ignore patterns
2. will also try to get the svn:ignore property for a file, which doesn't make sense

**Update**

A better solution, but not as good as Lazy Badger's:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                       

import os
import subprocess

# Run command and store output in variable, splitting into a list on newlines                                           
paths =  subprocess.check_output(['svn', 'list', '-R']).splitlines()

for path in paths:
    # [-1] is Python notation for "the last character in the string", so...                                             
    # look for a trailing path separator to indicate a "directory"                                                      
    if path[-1] == os.sep:
        ignores = subprocess.check_output(['svn', 'propget', 'svn:ignore', path])
        if ignores:
            print path
            print ignores
```

Comment: @LazyBadger Ah, even better.  I didn't know propget supported the recursive option.  Thank you for sharing--I'm glad I know now.